# Selenium by data-react-id attribute on web scrape

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to scrape some data from Yahoo! Finance, but I've noticed that most of the elements have something called data-reactid. So when using selenium locate the element by, when I try to name or id I get an error each time. I've never used the XPath method, but could someone take a look at https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/IBM.

I want to save `data-reactid='35'` which are the $165 close price to a variable name data for example and then print the variable.

Comment: Where is your code? What exactly are you trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following CSS selector (here I used a nested element structure):

```
price_per_share = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#quote-header-info > div > div > div > span[data-reactid='35']")
print(price_per_share.text)
```

It's more accurate. Hope it helps you!

PS: `data-reactid` is custom attribute of the span element.

Comment: @RobertBailey, so it solved your problem described in question? If yes -- check a tick near my answer, please. According to your comment -- it's another question.

Comment: What if I wanted to get the text from the video headline. For example, they use <!-- react-text: 18 --> to print one of the video headlines. Would this be the proper code:.......................................................‌​............. header_info = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#Main > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > u[data-reactid='18']") print(header_info.text) –

Comment: how do i ask you another question. i liked your help on the first question

Comment: @RobertBailey, you can use the same logic for that. I don't know which video you want to get.

Comment: The first video, " IBM CEO: Prepare for AI to change the world ". I tried the same logic, but with U instead of span, and nothing appears. It uses react-text instead of data-reactid

Comment: @RobertBailey, so use `react-text` attribute for that. Any other problems?

Comment: How do you know how many / and which div's to count? I saw (for the first question I asked) you used 3 div's, and I counted that those were open on the developer tool set. But for the video, there are so many open div's and also there is not a span infront of the class that contains the text. It uses <u class>

Comment: @RobertBailey, yes, you are right. By "logic" I mean another thing, it does not matter how many divs or which name of the attribute is used. Hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: In your original code, I took out one of the div> and it gives me an error, I think because we have not "tabbed" over to the right <div>. So what do you mean it doesn't matter how many divs we use?

Comment: @RobertBailey, for example, if you have 3 nested divs -- CSS selector will be `div > div > div`, if you 2 nested divs -- `div > div`. And so on.

Comment: And since the video box is <u class> and not <span class>, would it be propert to use u[element] not span[element]

Comment: @RobertBailey, yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
css_locator = 'div.quote-header-section span[data-reactid="35"]'
price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_locator).text
print price
```

Comment: Rep of 1157 and you are not yet aware that a good answer requires an explanation?